# Getting two values from a table string using regex in php

Tags: php, regex, string, text

Having this input string:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/test       591G  436G  132G  77% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /v
udev             15G   12K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  200K  3.0G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             15G     0   15G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/fb          74G   52M   70G   1% /mnt
```

Can someone provide me a regex to get:

- Total space (`591G`)
- Used space (`436G`)
- Used space % (`77%`)

... so I can store them in three different variables, `total_space` and `used_space` and `used_space_percent`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that just a string?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Yes, it's an string.

Comment: This appears to be output of `df -h` Unix command. Why not do this using some Unix commands

Comment: @anubhava Sure, why not? What can I use to get only those values?

Comment: Do you want occupation for 1rst line only or for all the lines?

Comment: @Toto Just the first. It's the only line where the total is calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

```
$str = "Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/test       591G  436G  132G  77% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /v
udev             15G   12K   15G   1% /dev
tmpfs           3.0G  200K  3.0G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             15G     0   15G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/fb          74G   52M   70G   1% /mnt";

preg_match('/\R\S+\h+(?<total>\S+)\h+(?<used>\S+)\h+\S+\h+(?<percent>\S+)/', $str, $m);
print_r($m);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /dev/test       591G  436G  132G  77%
    [total] => 591G
    [1] => 591G
    [used] => 436G
    [2] => 436G
    [percent] => 77%
    [3] => 77%
)
```

If you don't want named capture group:

```
preg_match('/\R\S+\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+\S+\h+(\S+)/', $str, $m);
```

Comment: Thanks Toto! Is there any way to clean the array and remove the duplicated values?

Comment: @Avión: Just remove `?<field_name>` from each capture group.

Comment: How can I do that? I dont see `?<field_name>` on the regex? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can split string by space delimiter using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$arr = preg_split("/\s+/", $str);
echo $arr[8]; // 591G
echo $arr[9]; // 436G
echo $arr[11]; // 77%
```

Check result of code in [demo](https://3v4l.org/oYrVn)